# Is there a plugin or a way in the wordpress that would let us have different versions of a post or page accessibe to users?

Tags: plugins, posts

I work on a website which talks about and teaches some educational subjects. It happens alot that I talk and explain about a software like a year ago and a new versions comes out.
Currently what I do, is I edit the post and add the new explanations, sometimes the old context is lost or summerized into a section at the end of the article.
I want to be able to have this old revision accessible to the viewers. Like what we have in the wordpress editor which shows several older versions which we can choose and compare. this way, I can address and navigate users to read about the older version using the revision they can have access to, and then update the main arctile with the newest information.

Do we have something like this in wordpress? if not whats other alternative for implementing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are after adding Wiki functionality to your Wordpress site(but with editing restricted to author).  See [this write up on the topic](http://www.wordyard.com/2010/08/03/change-is-good-but-show-your-work/) (complete with revision links above comments).

The above article uses the [Post Revision Display](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-revision-display/) plugin which hasn't been updated for a while. However, as he is an tech writer and still using it, I assume it is still compatible with latest Wordpress. If not just search wordpress.org for other WordPress Wiki plugins, I'm not sure if or how those alternatives  will restrict revisions, but one may fit the bill.